# Windows 8.1 - InnoSetup compiled installer is rejected for security even the installer is code signed?

Tags: windows-installer, installation, windows-8.1, inno-setup, code-signing

Windows XP,  VISTA, 7 using InnoSetup when i build installer of my application and then code sign them, they are accepted by operating systems with normal friendly dialog from operating system such as:

[image]

But now same way that working installer when is used under Windows 8.1 64-bit i am getting always this:

[image]

Now in 8.1 such dialog is very risky because everybody will click OK and that cancel the installation, many users do not click the more information. How to make my InnoSetup compiled installer safely distributable for Windows 8.1? So that my installer do not face risks.

Please suggest/advise.

EDIT: I have tried this but still same:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/10/13/stranger-danger-introducing-smartscreen-application-reputation.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2012/08/14/microsoft-smartscreen-amp-extended-validation-ev-code-signing-certificates.aspx

> can it be EV Code signing issue? my code signing was not from Symantec and DigiCert, could that cause it?

EDIT: my code sign vendor site instructions

https://support.globalsign.com/customer/portal/articles/1491089-kernel-mode-driver-signing-%E2%80%93-windows-7-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SmartScreen is an IE thing.  The only solution is to get "enough" people to download your application (using IE) that it raises your reputation above the warning threshold.

Signing does help with this -- the reputation of a signed file attaches to the signature rather than to the file, so once you're over the threshold you'll stay there as long as you keep using the same signature.  (And don't distribute malware, of course.)

You can "shortcut" the process a little if you bought an EV cert, which is a different (and probably more expensive) type offered by only a few vendors.  If you don't know whether you bought an EV cert or not, you probably didn't.

This is actually all explained in the links you included in the question. :)

Comment: So that means for Windows 8.1 and to get ride from that SmartSreen one should buy not regular code signing but specially: EV cert http://www.digicert.com/code-signing/ev-code-signing.htm

Comment: 1) a standard code signing cert will eventually bypass the Smartscreen once enough reputation is built, however, the only certificate that will immediately bypass the smartscreen is an EV certificate: http://www.digicert.com/code-signing/ev-code-signing.htm 2) We will ship out a token/usb stick with the certificate on it. EV requires the use of a token to sign the code. Only standard code signing certs can be issued as a pfx file.